# Python - understand the scope of the variable pass to a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, scope, python-3.5

I have a recursive function with an array as the parameter that stores the path as I travel a grid, from (0, 0) to (x, y), and I have to skipped some points that are defined as "unavailable"

I implement my function like this

```
unAvailablePoint = [(1, 2), (3, 0), (0, 3), (2, 3), (0, 1)]

def steppable(point):
    return point not in unAvailablePoint

def travel(x, y, path, visited):
    if x >= 0 and y >= 0 and steppable((x, y)):
        if (x, y) in visited:
            return visited[(x, y)]
        success = False
        if (x, y) == (0, 0) or travel(x-1, y, path, visited) or travel(x, y-1, path, visited):
            path = path + [(x, y)] #the path will remain empty even after the recursive call have done some changes to the path
            success = True
        visited[(x, y)] = success
        return success
    return False

path = []
visited = {}
travel(3, 3, path, visited)
print(path) //[]
```

As I print out the `path` at the end, it seems the `path` is still empty. This is not what I expected as a Python novice. Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Well, your travel function returns only `True`/`False`, so `path` changes stay in scope of that recursion step.

Comment: It's this is different in Java, which allows you to modify the parameter as the recursive step goes. As it back tracks, the caller should be able to get the updated value for the parameter that pass to the children recursive step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to append to the path and not initialize it every iteration of the recursion:

```
path.append( (x,y) ) #the path will remain empty even after the recursive call have done some changes to the path
```

instead of:

```
path = path + [(x, y)] #the path will remain empty even after the recursive call have done some changes to the path
```

This way, you are not initialize the list each iteration, so it will not be a local variable to the function.

Comment: It works. But why will we re-initialize the list as we use `path = path + [(x, y)]`?

Comment: Because the `path = path + [(x, y)]` is in the function, when you did this you made path as a local variable to the travel function. when you use append, you make sure that path is not initialized inside the function so he will not be a local variable to the function. @KesongXie

Comment: Another solution: `path += [(x, y)]`

Comment: I see. I think the difference why `path = path + [(x,y)]` won't work while `path += [(x,y)]` should fully depend on how the + and += operator being overloaded. The first one should return a new list object, why the second one would modify the existing path variable.